# Jquery .post not working on a popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am at my wits end with this, spent hours on it...

I have a div that pops up with a button, that button also fills data in to div html sections...

That all works, the bit that doesn't work is when i use ajax to post to a php file and back again.... Well it works but only on the second click not the first...

```
$.post("getprice.php", { unit: $('input[name=property]:checked').val() } ,function(data){
        $('#price').html(data);
     });

$timenow = time();
$unit=$_POST['unit'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM rl_pricing WHERE start_date < $timenow AND stop_date > $timenow AND unit=$unit";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $results );
echo "Price: ".$row['3day'];
```

Just doesn't seem to work on first click...

On this page http://offline.raileisure.com

click the get price button and it won't show the price... click away and click on it again and it works....

Hope that makes sense

EDIT:

So the code does do what its supposed to, but it just doesn't work on first click, but does on second.... its something to do with the popup div... if i get it to update on the same page its fine

Comment: Your AJAX post is working fine the first time the button is clicked, it seems that the response is not being placed into the page.

Comment: @Jamie - Thats what i am thinking but can't work out why

Comment: Also, the div is being populated with the correct value, first time. It's just not showing on the page. (but the div is being populated correctly the first time)

Comment: Yeah - but why isn't it showing :-(

Comment: Because the containing form is halfway down the page ;-)

Comment: and <div id="info"> is set to display:none;

Comment: See my answer below Lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the button is clicked, the price is added to a location that is currently hidden:

```
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
<form action="lee.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="75%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3">
<div id="extrasinfo"></div>
<div id="price">Price: 499</div>
<input id="btowelsinput" type="hidden" value="" name="btowelsinput">
<input id="bcotinput" type="hidden" value="" name="bcotinput">
<input id="bbouncyinput" type="hidden" value="" name="bbouncyinput">
<input id="bpetfeeinput" type="hidden" value="" name="bpetfeeinput">
<input id="boveroccinput" type="hidden" value="" name="boveroccinput">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is, when you click the button, there's 2 HTML elements with the id "price". This isn't allowed in HTML and your code is getting confused. It's adding the price to the first div with that id but not the second (the one you're expecting).

**UPDATE 2**

By the looks of it, the entire HTML segment where the price should be displayed is being duplicated on your page.

Comment: @Jamie - Where do you see these multiple id price's ?? i have searched the code and the source from the browser and i cannot see 2 ?? i have also changed it to price2 and it still acts the same :-(

Comment: You're generating it somewhere in the Javascript. If you look at the "Generated Source" in Firefox, after you've clicked the button, you'll see that you're duplicating that whole block somewhere.

Comment: Click the "Get Price" button, View Generated Source, and search for id="price"

Comment: I don't understand, that section is hard coded, i can't replicate that fact your getting it twice, and anyway i have renamed it andit still doesn't work so its not that...

Comment: Remaing it wont matter if the duplication is being caused by your JS somewhere. It looks like somewhere you're grabbing the whole block and adding it too another container. That may not be the case but it does look like it could be.

Comment: its a popup facebox div box.... its something to do with that... if i move that price div on the front page it works on first click

Comment: What is a popup facebox div box? Moving the price div outside doesn't change what I've said. If that whole container is being duplicated somewhere, taking the price div out of that just means the price is no longer being duplicated. In fact it makes the case for duplication even stronger!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Firefox 5 and IE 9. Have you tried clearing your cache?

I'd recommend downloading Firebug for firefox [(here)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) if you don't have it already. You can easily see ajax calls.

Another good program is Fiddler2 ([here](http://download.cnet.com/Fiddler2/3000-2381_4-10629421.html))

Comment: I've just tried in Firefox here and it still doesn't come up first time :-(

Comment: Are you talking about the "Get Price" button on the right-hand side of the application (under "Book Now")? It only takes one click for me. I also did a firebug trace and the ajax post is definitely being sent

Comment: I've edited my response with links to Firebug and fiddler. Both excellent programs. Firebug is nice because you can view/edit html on the fly, as well as debug your javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug, I can see that the post is being fired and the response is coming back as 499.

Is the code wrapped in the ready function? `$(function() { });`